# AngularJs - Switch directive mode

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to create a header directive with swappable controls. The header contains a search input, which stays the same throughout the application, and a number of buttons, which differ from page to page.

I considered usage of child directives that can be passed as arguments, but they are giving me a `multidir` error due to multiple template requests:

#### header.html

```
<div class="header">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

#### mode1.html

```
<div class="controls">
  <buutton>Foobar</button>
</div>
```

#### Usage:

```
 <app-header mode1>
```

My second thought was to use a shared service that initializes the available controls by determining the active mode. That seems a little weird, though.

**How can I create such a directive with different modes?**

Comment: Some more code would be very helpful to understand exactly where you are coming from and what the end result should kind of look like. Maybe a plunker or jsBin for that matter?

Comment: Is the header completely different from page to page, or do you have pages using the same header header?

Comment: There are pages that use the same header

Comment: If you could change a bit to `<app-header><model1></model1></app-header>`, that will be possible with a transuclution concept.